# Firefox won't set input.value in keydown handler... but it works while debugging?

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom

It's late at night, I'm behind deadline, and I'm wrestling with a problem that seems very, very strange to me.  Maybe it's something obvious I'm missing 'cause I'm tired, but I dunno... anyway here's my test case:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function NoEsc(e)
    {
      e = e||window.event;
      var k = e.keyCode||e.which;
      if (k!=27) return true;
      var s = e.target||e.srcElement;
      s.value = "ESCAPE PRESSED!";
      //alert("It works when this alert is shown!");
      return false;
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body onload="document.getElementById('in1').onkeydown=NoEsc;">
  <input type="text" id="in1" value="ORIGINAL VALUE">
</body>
</html>
```

The idea is that on my page, pressing ESC doesn't reset the whole form, just the element that has focus.  For the test case above, I just make ESC manually set the text in the input element to "ESCAPE PRESSED!", then cancel the keydown event.

In IE (v9) this works perfectly.  In Firefox (v14.0.1), however, nothing happens when ESC is pressed inside the input.  **But** if I uncomment the `alert` line, or if I set a breakpoint in FireBug before the `s.value = "ESCAPE PRESSED!"` statement, **then** it works perfectly.

I've been working on this for an hour or two, and at this point I'm throwing up my hands in disgust and posting the problem here.  I've no idea why it doesn't work.

Can someone help me out?  Have I missed something obvious?  Thanks.

Comment: Mmh... it seems to be related with `onkeydown`. It works fine with `onkeyup`.

Comment: I need to use onkeydown:  I have to cancel it, so that the default ESC operation doesn't take place (resetting the entire form).  Once cancelled, onkeypress and onkeyup won't occur.

Comment: But is the form reset on keydown or keyup? If you don't prevent the event on keydown but on keyup, it will be fine. It seems that Firefox somehow resets the field value to the previous/original value. If you have a look here http://jsfiddle.net/UQqvN/1/ and type some characters and/or press escape, the value is changed. But if you then press and hold ESC *again*, the previous value is shown. I cannot really explain way, but that might be the reason why the value does not change.

Comment: You can see that FF is doing *something* to the field on ESC keydown or maybe keypress... it ought to be resetting to "ORIGINAL VALUE" but for some reason it's resetting to the last value the field had before it was programatically changed (i.e. whatever you last typed before pressing ESC).  That looks like a bug in Firefox to me - that shouldn't ever happen, unless you change `element.defaultValue` in your script.  In any case it's no help to me - I have to prevent it, because I don't want the *other* fields in my form to change!

Comment: Does this happen in earlier versions? Maybe you should file a bug report.

Comment: Curiouser and curiouser.  I added a 2nd textbox to the form on your jsfiddle page, with no associated onkeyup event.  ESC does nothing inside this field.  ESC in the first field affects it (only) as before.  Apparently 'ESC' isn't a shortcut key to for a form reset or to a form reset button in FF, the way it is in IE.  So the behaviour here has nothing to do with form resets... Instead it's as if the textbox is storing the last typed value, and restoring it on ESC... and some Googling... and yes, it is, and it's a known Firefox bug:  https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=598819

Comment: Since it's a FF bug I'll have to work around it.  I think I can do that by attaching NoEsc to both onkeydown and onkeypress as well (or maybe onkeyup).  Thanks for your help Felix.

Comment: Yes, attaching NoEsc to onkeypress as well as onkeydown works.

Comment: Glad you figured it out :) I guess you can provide your workaround together with all the information about the bug as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been having problems with this myself today (ff v16.0.2 @ winxp). Especially with the annoying reset (of the script-set value) to the previous (user-entered) value at ESC. Playing around with this I've noticed that TAB-ing out and back again would bake in the script-set string. And surely enough, the following appears (so far) to be a decent workaround:

```
s.value = "ESCAPE PRESSED!";
s.blur();    // tab out
s.focus();   // tab right back in
return false;
```

Very strange. (This definitely seems to be a bug.)

Cheers!

Comment: Dejan, see my comment above from 2012-07-22 21:52... it's a known bug in Firefox.  Details here:  http://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=598819

Comment: Ok. Wow. Didn't see the "show X more comments" clicky. (This is only my second post to the forum, sorry.) Yes, at the very least the blur/refocus explains why uncommenting the alert() line in the original listing made it work. Anyway. Thanks for your own approach and for finding us the bugreport!